# Encrypted Periodic Backups in RavenDB

Tags: backup, ravendb

We've started using the [Periodic Backup bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/extending/bundles/periodic-backup) in RavenDB to export data from our Server to an Azure Blob Storage Container incrementally.

The source database uses the [Encryption bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/extending/bundles/encryption) to safeguard data at rest, however after testing the restore it's clear the backup files either do not encrypt the data or keep a copy of the key in the backup file for restoration.

How can we configure RavenDB to encrypt backups, periodic or otherwise, so they remain safeguarded at rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Periodic Backup uses an export method to do that, which store the data in clear text.

Actually [backing up (Raven.Backup.exe)](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/java/server/administration/backup-and-restore) will store the data in encrypted format, but will include the key in the backup (there is an option to prevent that), so you can actually restore the backup on another machine.

Comment: Thank you Ayende, how would you restore the backup if you've removed the key?  Is there an option when restoring to provide the key?

Comment: Further to this; running `Raven.Backup.exe -?` shows no flag to prevent that; nor is there indication of this in the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Backup/Program.cs)

Comment: Raven.Backup doesn't expose this. That is how it behaves by default.
The studio (assuming you are human, not a machine), does behave in this way.

Comment: When restoring, you can edit the Database.Document file to include the  secret key

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Ayende Rahien's answer, use [Raven backup](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/java/server/administration/backup-and-restore) instead of export.

If you need to remove the encryption key in the backup, use [a curl Raven backup request with `DatabaseDocument` containing an empty `SecuredSettings` property](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/java/server/bundles/encryption#encryption--backups).

Example from the link above:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/databases/Northwind/admin/backup?incremental=false" \
     -d "{\"BackupLocation\":\"c:\temp\backup\Northwind\",\"DatabaseDocument\":{\"SecuredSettings\":{},\"Settings\":{\"Raven/ActiveBundles\": \"Encryption\"},\"Disabled\":false,\"Id\":null}}"
```

Here's the posted data in a readable format:

`{
  "BackupLocation": "c:\temp\backup\Northwind",
  "DatabaseDocument": {
    "SecuredSettings": {}, // <- EncryptionKey not present here. 
    "Settings": {
      "Raven/ActiveBundles": "Encryption"
    },
    "Disabled":false,
    "Id":null
  }
}`